# How to set a property of a base class when constructing an inherited widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to create an inherited `AppBar` called `HomeAppBar`, which inherits from `CommonAppBar`, which inherits from `AppBar`. `CommonAppBar` sets the background to purple and `HomeAppBar` sets title to `Hourlogger`

```dart
class CommonAppBar extends AppBar {
  CommonAppBar() : super(backgroundColor: Colors.purple);
}

class HomeAppBar extends CommonAppBar {
  HomeAppBar() : super(title: Text("Hourlogger"));
}
```

However the compiler says

> The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.
> Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.

I was under the impression that `CommonAppBar` should inherit the `title` from the `AppBar`. How should I go about setting the `title` in my custom `AppBar`?

Comment: `super(title: Text(...))` is equal to `CommonAppBar()`. I think you already know how to add a named parameter in a constructor. Just don't forget to pass the `title` property from `CommonAppBar` to its parent class via `super(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CommonAppBar extends AppBar {
  final Widget title;
  CommonAppBar({this.title}) : super(backgroundColor: Colors.purple, title: title);
}

class HomeAppBar extends CommonAppBar {
 HomeAppBar() : super(title: Text("Hourlogger"));
}
```

This should work where you first take the title parameter from the constructor and pass it to super